# django template just reloads when clicking a link pointing to another template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

the template home in my django contains a url pointing to another page but when clicking this link , the home template just reloads here is the code for the urls.py, views.py and home.html

this is urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from pizza import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'order/',views.order,name='order'),
]
```

this is views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request,'pizza/home.html')

def order(request):
    return render(request,'pizza/order.html')
```

this is home.html

```
  <h3>
    Nandias Garder
</h3>
<a href="{% url 'order' %}"> order a pizza</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your urls formatting is wrong. you should try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^order/',views.order,name='order'),
]
```

if you notice here I used `^$` to make sure the home url only catches the empty url.

in your urls, the second url (home url) will match with every string. you can go to admin, because it's defined before home url.